# Setting AuthExceptionRetryInterval property in Spring Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I've got a Spring Boot application, which integrates the Spring Kafka project.

I'd like to set the `AuthExceptionRetryInterval` property in my `application.properties`.

It is being mentioned in https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerProperties.html

Although, I can't figure out the correct way to set it. I am not sure, if and how the "relaxed binding" of Spring interfers. Neither is the auto-completion of IntelliJ suggesting it. I am also not sure, on how to set Apache configs properly in a Spring environment.

It has to be done through a property, setting it through code is not the solution I am looking for.

Way's I've tried...

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.auth.exception.retry.interval=60ms

spring.kafka.listener.consumer.properties.auth.exception.retry.interval=60ms

spring.kafka.listener.consumer.auth.exception.retry.interval=60ms
```

Could anyone tell me what I need do wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: This is the docs page on setting client properties https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka.additional-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because a getter/setter exists doesn't mean it's a native Kafka property.

Specifically, that property is not a [Kafka client configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#configuration), so cannot be passed though to the consumer via configuration.

You could define your own autowired property, then call the setter in code using that value, instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am also having a similar issue and not able to set this value. Ours is also a spring boot kafka consumer application with yml files and a KafkaListener coded as such

```
@KafkaListener(
      groupId = "${spring.kafka.topic.consumer-topic-group-id}"},
      topics = "${spring.kafka.topic.consumer-topic}")
```

and the yml file is as follows

```html
kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    producer:    
      retries: 0
      acks: all
      key-serializer: XXX
      value-serializer: YYY
    topic:
      name: topic1
    topic-json:
      name: topic2  
    consumer:
      group-id: myGroup
      sleeponerrortime: 30
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: XXX
      value-deserializer: YYY
      authExceptionRetryInterval: 8000 // Does not work 
    properties:  
      spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: YYY
      spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: XXX
      enable-auto-commit: false
      authExceptionRetryInterval: 23000 /// Does not work 
      properties:
```

Would really appreciate if someone could provide me sample yml files and/or code ? When the broker goes down , our consumer also goes down and we would like for it to keep trying before giving up on one try.